# Why this Go program not enter deadlock status as expected?

Tags: go, concurrency

I am a newbie in Go, i wrote this code and hope it will enter deadlock status, but failed.

```
var mux sync.Mutex

func main() {
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(1)
    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
    go func() {
        log.Println("Trying to Lock the Mux")
        mux.Lock()
        log.Println("The mux is Locked")
    }()
  }
  runtime.Gosched()
}
//Output:
//2017/01/17 08:59:42 Trying to Lock the Mux
//2017/01/17 08:59:42 The mux is Locked
//2017/01/17 08:59:42 Trying to Lock the Mux
//2017/01/17 08:59:42 Trying to Lock the Mux
```

As you can see. this code run well and print something and then quit without any deadlock error. For I know, the first **go func(){}** goroutine has returned and locked the mux then quit. But the other two goroutines will be blocked because the mux has already blocked.

The function **runtime.Gosched()** should push the main goroutine to the only FIFO queue(**runtime.GOMAXPROCS(1)**) right? why it can be excute before the left two goroutine that already in the queue?

BTW,this following code will return the deadlock error as expected

```
var mux sync.Mutex

func main() {
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(1)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(3)
    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            log.Println("Trying to Lock the Mux")
            mux.Lock()
            log.Println("The mux is Locked")

        }()
    }
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: The runtime.Gosched does nothing here, so I'm not sure the intent is. You're program doesn't deadlock, the main goroutine continues and exits.

Comment: As i know , the Gosched() will push the main goroutine back to the queue and  wait all the goroutines done.

Comment: I'm not sure where you got the idea that Gosched puts the goroutine in a blocking queue, but that's incorrect. The docs say "Gosched yields the processor, allowing other goroutines to run. It does not suspend the current goroutine, so execution resumes automatically."

Answer (score 2):

A deadlock is a condition where **all** the goroutines are in waiting state (waiting for lock or reading from channel etc). The reason is simple, if all of them are waiting then there is no one left that can do something that lead to any of the waiting goroutines to continue. In your case your main function, which is also a goroutine is not in waiting state. When the main goroutine exits the process exits too.

> The function runtime.Gosched() should push the main goroutine to the
>   only FIFO queue(runtime.GOMAXPROCS(1)) right? why it can be excute
>   before the left two goroutine that already in the queue?

The queue is a schedule queue. The runtime will pick a goroutine from the queue, run it for some time, pause it, pick another goroutine.

Comment: It is a FIFO but it is used for scheduling the goroutines i.e the runtime will pick goroutines to schedule using FIFO policy from this queue. FIFO is just how you put and fetch items from a queue, what you do with those items is not what FIFO is about.

Answer (score 1):

For your code:

```
var mux sync.Mutex

func main() {
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(1)
    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
    go func() {
        log.Println("Trying to Lock the Mux")
        mux.Lock()
        log.Println("The mux is Locked")
    }()
  }
  runtime.Gosched()
}
```

There is no deadlock, for

> func (m *Mutex) Lock()
>
> Lock locks m. If the lock is already in use,
> the calling goroutine blocks until the mutex is available.

So the second and third goroutine just wait there. This is [busy waiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting). then the main goroutine exit, so the second and third goroutine also exist.